# Do you need the Django template brackets to pass string values in a form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have the following form in a Django HTML template.

I found two different syntaxes that both work to pass string data from my form to the linked view function.

Please see the first radio input and then compare it the the second radio input to see the different syntax (on has brackets, one doesn't).

```
<form action="{% url 'shipment:createAccount' 1  %}" method="post">

{% csrf_token %}

<input type="radio" name="question_1" value="Option1">Option 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="question_1" value="{{ 'Option2'  }}">Option 2<br>

<input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
</form>
```

I've found that my code works both ways.  I was wondering if there is a functional difference between them, and if so, which one is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the second way is kind of overkill:

```
<input type="radio" name="question_1" value="{{ 'Option2'  }}">Option 2<br>
```

You're telling the template engine to parse `'Option2'` python statement. Since `'Option2'` python statement yields a string, the template engine will substitute it with:

```
<input type="radio" name="question_1" value="Option2">Option 2<br>
```

Which is exactly the same as your first way. You're creating a little overhead by doing it the second way.

Brackets are used inside templates to perform some kind of computation inside the template domain. Like accessing a `view`'s variable or object method.

To answer your question, you **don't** need the brackets syntax to include *literals* in the template. You need them to output variable values in it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot.  I have a follow up question:  Do I need the brackets when I have a text input?  E.g. <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="{{ first_name }}" />
?

Comment: I saw this in an example.  The reason I ask is because I'm not using the brackets to output variable values in my template, but rather pass the value of the text input.

Comment: Ok, if `first_name` is a variable inside the template's context then you need the brackets. If `first_name` doesn't exist you won't output anything on `value` attribute. In the case of `name` and `id` attributes they are just normal html attributes and their value is `first_name` literal. Try to pass a variable called `first_name` to the template and you'll see its content reflected in the textbox.